# How to configure jwplayer 5.9 to auto play ads and ask user for playing video

Tags: jwplayer

I am trying to configure jwplayer 5.9 to auto-play ad. After done with playing ad jwplayer should request user to play video ( ad auto-play as true but video auto-play to be false).

Comment: How are you playing the ads?

Comment: Thanks alot Ethan for being with me. Found solution and it's working fine :)

Comment: Np, glad you got it working. :)